# Bash grammar manual

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm looking for bash syntax, grammar book difference from "Bash Reference Manual"(i found it to be a little incoherent, my purpose requires near mathematic aproach to scripts elaboration). Any ideas ?

Comment: The POSIX shell grammar is described here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10 (see that whole page for the complete description of the command language). Bash implements an extended version of this.

Comment: You should meet [Tim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:674+[bash]) -- or at least, go through some of the questions they've asked.

Comment: See [@schily](/users/120884)'s https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01333.html (in a thread started by those guys mentioned by Basil)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there are good enough formal grammars for Bash.

In a few days (September 18<sup>th</sup> 2017), there are two Gallium seminars about that question (at INRIA Paris), by [Y. Régis-Gianas](http://gallium.inria.fr/seminaires/annonces/20170918.Yann.Regis-Gianas) (about *Parsing POSIX shell*) and by [N.Jannerod](http://gallium.inria.fr/seminaires/annonces/20170918.Nicolas.Jeannerod) (about *Formalising an intermediate language for POSIX shell*).

<sup>(Gallium folks like hot research topics, so I would believe these are difficult subjects; I guess they would publish something about this)</sup>

Comment: Some related discussions ([1](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01266.html), [2](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01232.html)) on the austin-group mailing list about the POSIX shell grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I found a BNF grammar of BASH V2 in the appendix of the following book: "Learning the bash Shell, 2nd Edition". It is still accessible [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/1565923472/syntax/lbs.appd.div.3).